# PrimeFaces 7.0 getCallbackParams() not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-7.0

I just upgraded from PrimeFaces 6.2 to 7.0 and I'm unable to find [`getCallbackParams()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#getCallbackParams--). In PrimeFaces 6.2 it wasn't deprecated nor there was an hint of it being moved in further releases.

Some of the [`RequestContext`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.2/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) functions were moved to [`PrimeFaces.current().ajax()`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/7.0/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.html#ajax--) (like `addCallbackParam()`) but it wasn't there either.

Has it been removed or moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still do so by calling:

```
PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance().getCallbackParams();
```

This is just what the [`org.primefaces.PrimeFaces.Ajax`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/db1f4b76160799f2031f032ea101357e8775c2cf/src/main/java/org/primefaces/PrimeFaces.java#L300) class is doing:

```
public void addCallbackParam(String name, Object value) {
        getRequestContext().getCallbackParams().put(name, value);
}

protected PrimeRequestContext getRequestContext() {
    return PrimeRequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
}
```

Comment: We should probably add getCallBackParams to the PrimeFaces.current().ajax() methods.